# OpenCV how To convert Mat to uchar [] []

Tags: opencv

I have the following code:

```
Mat image = cvLoadImage("our path ");
```

How do I convert the result to a two dimensional array of uchar?   Please help me  know how to read it as bytes and put it in the array.
plz can you tell me how to display the resulat as array i have problem with coding it .

Answer (score 2):

First, cvLoadImage() returns IplImage* not Mat. It is converted implicitly to Mat, so you can use it but it won't be released properly, leading to memory leak. You should use [imread](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imread) instead.

As for the question itself, you can use [ptr](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-ptr) function. For example:

```
uchar* p = image.ptr<uchar>(i);
```

p is now pointing to i-th line of image. You can work with it as usual array of uchar (read, change, copy, and so on).

Comment: Hello Thank you but my problem is displaying the result and getting the result into array and i have problems with displaying the result from pointer so if u can plz can you help with code i read a lot of forms and they say the same thing .

Comment: Can you write the code for me plz nthing is working with me .

Comment: In what form you want to display it, as image that shown on the screen or display values of pixels, or something else?

Comment: i want it in bytes i think pixels or sth like that i just want numbers not special char and thank you